# Python Bar charts are overlapping

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have plotted a bar chart using python's numpy and matplotlib, everything was fine except the spaces between the grouped bars. The grouped bar charts are overlapping, in actual scenario they should have enough space between them. Here is the code implemented.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

N = 5
shd0hrs = (195, 198, 195, 193, 270)
shd1hrs = (159, 160, 148, 155, 208)
shd2hrs=(55, 49, 48, 39, 56)
shd6hrs=(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
shd7ahrs=(21, 20, 18, 17, 26)
shd8hrs=(43, 38, 35, 31, 42)

width = 0.30       # the width of the bars

ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups


fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

rectshd0= ax.bar(ind,shd0hrs,width,color='r')
rectshd1= ax.bar(ind+width,shd1hrs,width,color='g')
rectshd2= ax.bar(ind+2*width,shd2hrs,width,color='b')
rectshd6= ax.bar(ind+3*width,shd6hrs,width,color='y')
rectshd7a= ax.bar(ind+4*width,shd7ahrs,width,color='m')
rectshd8= ax.bar(ind+5*width,shd8hrs,width,color='c')

# add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
ax.set_ylabel('GlareHrs/yr')
ax.set_title('West Orientation')
ax.set_xticks(ind+width)
ax.set_xticklabels( ('8am-10am', '10am-12pm', '12pm-2pm', '2pm-4pm', '4pm-6pm') )

ax.legend((rectshd0[0],rectshd1[0],rectshd2[0],rectshd6[0],rectshd7a[0],rectshd8[0]),('E1-geo0','E1-geo1','E1-geo2','E1-geo6','E1-geo7a','E1-geo8'))

def autolabel(rects):
    # attach some text labels
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height, '%d'%int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rectshd0)
autolabel(rectshd1)
autolabel(rectshd2)
autolabel(rectshd6)
autolabel(rectshd7a)
autolabel(rectshd8)

pyplot.show()
```

The resultant bar chart appears like this.[image]

I played around with np.arange() but no use, I don't know if i am missing anything. Also I would like to know if i can bring up more aesthetic colors in the chart. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting `width = 0.15`? I don't know if it has to be under 1 in total.

When doing this, the bars are plotted fine:

[image]

Comment: thanks it worked but the x-axes labels are to be adjusted to be in the middle of each group of bars and also more space between them. Also  Is a way  to prevent xtick_lables overlapping on chart?